# Angular ui-router different view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

For my project I want a different view for my login page, 
If I use template directive only angular wrap my login page into index.html (the template of the app)

```
  .state('login',{
        url:'/',
        controller:'loginController',
        templateUrl: './components/login/login.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

I want independant page for this, how I can do that ?

Comment: What is your question again? It look like you're  doing the right thing here - You created a state for the login page and you can redirect the user to that state

Comment: I use the directe ui-view. the result is note different view from layout the view is wrapped into the layout.

Comment: Did you try replacing `templateUrl` with `redirectTo` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720267/how-to-navigate-one-page-to-another-page-using-angularjs

Comment: I try now. thet bad !

Comment: is it multiple view? angularjs is a single page app.