# Node.js Route not working on Microsoft Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Hello I build a very basic Node.js app (without any framework),
I set up a route.
index.html and login.html

on my local machine (windows 10) its working fine. both files index.html and login.html show up in browser when I call them from url. like

**localhost/myapp  => loads index.html
localhost/myapp/login => loads login.html**

Now I deploy it on Microsoft Azure, and now only index file is loading, when i try to load myapp.azurewebsites.net/login it said this : **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

I have a web.config file with these settings

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

please guide me how to enable routing in node.js on azure. without any framework. there is no help on official docs.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Azure Node JS Starter Site or Node JS Empty Web App.

[image]

In those projects you will find the right web.config file that you need to run Node applications in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

well after a lot of search I figure out the solution.
you need to set web.config file from their demo project and upload into your own azure project.
    https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code in web.config file and see if it works.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more details on this error follow this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/01/30/the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-had-its-name-changed-or-is-temporarily-unavailable-404-63-0/).

Comment: your code will redirect me to index.html no matter what route I select

    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />

Comment: Are you referring to navigate one page to another page? follow the link below it could be a help then.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720267/how-to-navigate-one-page-to-another-page-using-angularjs